# this.props.children undefined when using react-router-redux

Tags: javascript, react-router-redux

I have followed the react-router-redux example on the [github page](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router-redux), but when I try to pass `{this.props.children}` to the `IndexRoute` and I try to log it, it's undefined.

The only error I get through the console is `Warning: You should not use <Route component> and <Route children> in the same route; <Route children> will be ignored`, which by googling this error, it's just one of those errors that people say just ignore it since it doesn't affect any of the code (for some reason).

`package.json`

```
....
"react": "^0.14.7",
"react-redux": "^4.4.0",
"react-router": "^4.0.0",
"react-router-dom": "^4.0.0",
"react-router-redux": "^4.0.8",
"redux": "^3.3.1",
"redux-thunk": "^1.0.3"
...
```

routes.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { Route, IndexRoute } from 'react-router';

import Items from "./components/Items"
import App1Container from "./containers/App1Container";
import ItemDetailContainer from "./containers/ItemDetailContainer";

export default (
  <Route path="/" component={App1Container}>
    <IndexRoute component={Items} />
        <Route path="i/:id" name="item-detail" component={ItemDetailContainer} />
  </Route>
);
```

App.jsx

```
import React from "react"
import { render } from "react-dom"
import {
  createStore,
  compose,
  applyMiddleware,
  combineReducers,
} from "redux"
import { Provider } from "react-redux"
import { Router, Route, browserHistory, IndexRoute } from 'react-router';
import { syncHistoryWithStore, routerReducer } from 'react-router-redux'
import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history';

import thunk from 'redux-thunk'

import * as reducers from './reducers'
import routes from './routes';

let finalCreateStore = compose(
  applyMiddleware(thunk),
  window.devToolsExtension ? window.devToolsExtension() : f => f
)(createStore);
let reducer = combineReducers({
    ...reducers,
    routing: routerReducer
});
let store = finalCreateStore(reducer);
const history = syncHistoryWithStore(createBrowserHistory(), store);

const router = (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <Router history={history}>{routes}</Router>
      </Provider>
);

render(router, document.getElementById('App'));
```

App1Container.jsx

```
import React from "react"
import Radium from "radium"

import { connect } from "react-redux"

import Headline from "../components/Headline"

@connect(state => ({
  items: state.items,
}))
@Radium
export default class App1Container extends React.Component {
  render() {
      console.log(this.props.children)
    return (
        <div>
            {/* just a an h1 tag with some text in it */}
            <Headline/> 
            {this.props.children}
        </div>

    )
  }
}
```

App1Container would render the Headline component successfully but not this.props.children.

[image: Here is an image of the props for the <Router>]

[image: And an image for the props of <Route> tag.]

Comment: is there anything else in the `this.props`?

Comment: @BobbyMatson check post for this.props images

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? I'm having a similar issue

Comment: @jona unfortunately I still haven't and still looking for a solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In react-router v4 you no longer nest routes.

```
<Route path="/" component={App1Container}>
    <IndexRoute component={Items} />
        <Route path="i/:id" name="item-detail" component={ItemDetailContainer} />
</Route>
```

Move your routes into your App1Container considering you always want it displayed. Then in your App1Container, add routes as follows:

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';

<Router>
    <Switch>
        <Route path="/" exact component={ Items } />
        <Route path="/i/:id" name="item-detail" component={ ItemDetailContainer } />
    </Switch>
</Router>
```

Comment: That is not strictly true. You can nest `Route` components in v4 just fine. It's in fact pretty comon. https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/basic but you either have to choose `<Route children={...}>` (Same as `<Route>{...}</Route>`) or `<Route component={...}>` like the error in OP's post states.

Comment: You don't really nest `<Route><Route></Route></Route>` anymore. You route to a component and you could put __nested__ routes in the top level route's component.